# Drop down button for my s

Tags: html

I want a drop down button for each of my search results so when clicked more information about the search result can be seen for each.

I do not want a drop down menu or box as the additional information will be a paragraph of information.

How do I do this?

Comment: I have tried drop boxes but i dont want the secondary information to be in a box. Is there a name/term for a buttom i can code that when clicked reveals information the can hide it as well. Like a minimize button or something that i can edit?

Comment: Hmmm, does this look similar to what you want? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Ah thats great! Thanks a lot just what I wanted :)

Comment: OK, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind jQuery, the jQuery UI project provides an Accordion widget, which provides a similar functionality: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

> Click headers to expand/collapse content that is broken into logical sections, much like tabs. Optionally, toggle sections open/closed on mouseover.
>
> The underlying HTML markup is a series of headers (H3 tags) and content divs so the content is usable without JavaScript.